# Issues with Boom Beach and Clash of Clans

Tags: iphone, game-center, clash-of-clans

My dad and I share an Apple ID (even though I've asked him time and time again to get his own for this reason). I accidentally clicked on both games my dad's account that is on his iPad and now I can't get to my own account. I have tried logging out of the Game Center and logging back in but neither will prompt to switch to my game. I also tried deleting it off my iPhone 6 and clearing it from the Game Center then re-download them and they both just pop up under my dad's account. Any advise to get my account back? Or start a new one?

Comment: Does getting a list of GC accounts help you out? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192541/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-all-your-game-center-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Apps such as Boom Beach and Clash of Clans use Game Center by default, the only way to force it to not use the Game Center account is to temporarily sign out of Game Center then start the app after a clean install. If your old account was not bound to either Facebook or Game Center, there is no definite way to recover it, but you can try by following these steps: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Recovering_a_lost_village_that_wasn%27t_linked_to_GC_or_GPlus